# Python map function strange behavior

Tags: python, dictionary

I´m running the following code:

```
selectedvalidations='1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
x=map(int,selectedvalidations.split(','))
print(list(x))
```

It prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

If I print again:

```
print(list(x))
```

It prints:

```
[]
```

Why?

Comment: In python3 map is a generator

Comment: because map is generator, you extract all from this generator and it is empty, try `new_x = list(x)` and `print(new_x)` how many times you want

Comment: The clearest thing to do in this case is to avoid map and use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

In python3 `map` is a generator. If you want to reuse the variable use

```
selectedvalidations='1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
x=list(map(int,selectedvalidations.split(',')))  #Encapsulate map in list
print(x)
```

Comment: why you use two times `list()` ?

Comment: Sorry did not see that. Thanks

Comment: Tks! In Python 2.7 the behavior is different, that is, I can use "x" map object many times without problem.

Comment: You are right in python2 map returns a list so you can use any  number of times.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to convert the generator into list in-place and hold the list in the variable

```
>>> selectedvalidations='1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
>>> x=list(map(int,selectedvalidations.split(',')))
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```